# How to find the unique solution to norm(a,2)==c; when c is a scalar and a=[x abs(1/x);x+1 1/x]

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I am trying to find the unique solution to the following equation using Matlab

```
               norm(a,2)=0.11
```

when `x` is a variable and `a=[x abs(1/x);x+1 1/x]`. `b` is the exact formulation of `norm(a,2)`, which I have gained:

```
syms x
a=[x abs(1/x);x+1 1/x];
b = norm(a,2)

b = max(abs(2*x + x*abs(x)^2 + 2*x*abs(x)^4 + abs(x)^4 + x^2*abs(x)^2 - (4*x*abs(x)^5 + 2*x*abs(x)^6 + 4*x*abs(x)^8 + abs(x)^8 + 8*x^2*abs(x)^3 + x^2*abs(x)^4 + 4*x^3*abs(x)^3 + 2*x^3*abs(x)^4 + 6*x^2*abs(x)^6 + x^4*abs(x)^4 + 4*x^3*abs(x)^6 + 4*x^2*abs(x)^8 + 4*x^2)^(1/2))/(2*abs(x)^3), abs(2*x + x*abs(x)^2 + 2*x*abs(x)^4 + abs(x)^4 + x^2*abs(x)^2 + (4*x*abs(x)^5 + 2*x*abs(x)^6 + 4*x*abs(x)^8 + abs(x)^8 + 8*x^2*abs(x)^3 + x^2*abs(x)^4 + 4*x^3*abs(x)^3 + 2*x^3*abs(x)^4 + 6*x^2*abs(x)^6 + x^4*abs(x)^4 + 4*x^3*abs(x)^6 + 4*x^2*abs(x)^8 + 4*x^2)^(1/2))/(2*abs(x)^3))^(1/2)
```

I have tried `solve()` and the following is the result:

```
solve(b==0.11,x) 
Warning: Cannot find explicit solution.
```

ans =
Empty sym: 0-by-1

Any help regarding the suitable method to solve the above equation will be appreciated.

Comment: Btw: `norm(a,2)` is equivalent to `norm(a)`, the `2` is redundant.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - might it be that there isn't a solution?

Comment: You want `fminsearch` or `fmincon`. You need to propose this as a minization approach to be able to solve it

Comment: Have you numerically checked that there are solutions?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know

```
norm(a) = max(svd(a))
```

`max` is a problem in this equation, that's why I would find and solve symbolic equations for the both `svd` results separately:

```
syms x
a=[x abs(1/x);x+1 1/x];

s = svd(a);

% svd 1
solve(s(1)==0.11,x) 

% svd 2
solve(s(2)==0.11,x)
```

Return value for svd 1:

```
Warning: Cannot solve symbolically. Returning a numeric approximation instead. 

ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882
```

Return value for svd 2:

```
Warning: Cannot find explicit solution. 

ans = Empty sym: 0-by-1
```

So the answer would be

```
ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882
```

If we had a solution for each svd part, we could find max() of them.

Here is a plot of both `svd` functions:

[image]

**UPDATE**

As we could see above, the solver switched to the numerical solver and found only one solution, although the plot shows us at least two possible solutions.

To find all solution (there can be actually more then two) I would directly use the numerical solver `vpasolve` and either input an initial guess or let the solver found solutions randomly:

```
vpasolve(s(1)==0.11,x,2) % input initial guess as 2
```

It returns the second solution:

```
ans = 2.2626424161863046178372248086765
```

Or use the random guess:

```
for n = 1:10 
    vpasolve(s(1)==0.11,x,'Random',true) % use random guess
end
```

It returns all found solution:

```
ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882 
ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882 
ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882
ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882 
ans = 2.2626424161863046178372248086765 %!!!
ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882
ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882
ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882
ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882
ans = -12.84595601211006224344551434882
```